# return a page after a few seconds

Tags: google-apps-script

I have:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Hello World');
}
```

When that has run, after 5 seconds, I want to run:

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('filename');
```

So the user sees the `Hello World`, and 5 secs later, sees the content of `filename`.

Can this be done?

Comment: Return a page instead of content, and use JavaScript in that first page to call the second function, which displays the file.

Comment: @tehhowch Please post an answer with your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlService allows you to deploy websites with client-side JavaScript. So, rather than try to use Apps Script to manage the webpage updating, use "normal" JavaScript to call your Apps Script functions:

1. Instead of ContentService, use HtmlService to return a page with the desired initial content.
2. Use JavaScript in that first page (e.g. a timer initiated by the completion of the webpage loading) to call the second Apps Script function (`google.script.run....`) which displays the file (or something).